# QGIS version 2.18.14 exporting georeferenced tiff file to kml

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

It seems everybody can use right-click on layers, and "save as" to export to .kml. I only get the opportunity to save as "GTiff".

What am I missing out here?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is you're trying to export a raster (tif) file to KML which, as far as I know, can only be done through plugins/scripts etc. Go to "Plugins"->"Manage and Install Plugins" and search for KMZ to see any plugin options, also see http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html to see how to use gdal to create a KML from a geotiff.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using "GEarthView" plugin. You just need to pick the layer You want to display and click plugin icon. This will launch GEarth with required layer displayed on a basemap.

When GE is running, You can export your view to kmz by choosing the place in ***"My Places -> place name -> Save place as"***.  [image]

At least it works in my case.
I know that this is not straightforward, simple walkaround but it works :)

Comment: I get the message "This plugin is broken 'module' object has no attribute 'qt4reactor'" when I try to intall it. :(