# QGIS Export to KML option missing

Tags: qgis, layer-to-kml

I have been trying to export a .tif raster to KML using QGIS. I have searched and watched multiple YouTube videos but I can't copy what they are instructing because the option so select KML is just missing from the drop down menu. I have also installed the KML tools plug in but I still can't find a way. When I right click on the layer and select "Save as" and go to the format drop down box there is just no option for KML. I have installed the latest versions of QGIS on multiple computers and this option is awlays missing for me. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: The list is inherited from GDAL ~ https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html which doesn't offer up a KML raster driver, though there is `KMLSuperoverlay,` which might be said to be missing

Answer (score 4):

KML is a (mostly) vector format, i do not think you can export raster data into .kml with QGIS.

See other questions/answers here:
[Can QGIS save a Multi-band Raster image as KML/KMZ?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346714/can-qgis-save-a-multi-band-raster-image-as-kml-kmz)